Laravel 11 Socialite - how to get Google user with Javascript token
I have a Vue application which login user with Google JS SDK. Javascript get access_token and send this token to Laravel. What I expect is the Socialite should be able to login to Google API with this token and get user data and login user. I tried this
// $token is that one which Javascript send to Laravel
$user_google_data = Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($token);

But this throws me an error:
Copy
resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid Credentials"
}
 {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException(code: 401): Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
  \"error\": \"invalid_request\",
  \"error_description\": \"Invalid Credentials\"
}

The credentials should be valid because if I change the credentials I get another error invalid client. I am not sure if the js token is valid too or how to use it properly. The problem could be if the token would be one time token cause I get this token from online application which send this token to Google API. But I dont know.
Does somebod know what is wrong with this flow?
Thnaks.
